# Minimum API level required for non-Support Library android projects

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-api-levels

Does anyone know what the lowest minimum API level is for Android projects that don't require any Support Libraries? 21 or 22 was my guess but I may be wrong. I don't need any Support Library features for my future project.

Comment: It may be as old as API 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know what the lowest minimum API level is for Android projects that don't require any Support Libraries?

API Level 1. After all, the Support Library did not come into existence until after API Level 11 shipped. We developed Android apps for a few years without such a library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what is the min sdk to support in order not to have to use support library then the answer is there is not such a thing. You will end up using a support library in the future because android api is always being updated.

If you do not want to use library supports then you need to develop apps to use only basic features including in API 1.